# How can i insert metadata details or expand new properties using stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I just want to  apply what the stripe's docs said about adding the Metadata property and then i can add everything and it can be displayed in the webhook, but i have tried to add the metadata , even to expand details but i didnt know how , this is the code :

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'price' => $price_id,
       'metadata' =>['prod_id' => ' TEST'], //// i want to store something like that
      'quantity' => 1,
    ],
  ],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add metadata to the object, but not inside the line-items array.

Add metadata like below

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'price' => $price_id,
      'quantity' => 1,
    ],
  ],
  'metadata' =>['prod_id' => ' TEST'], //// i want to store something like that
  'mode' => 'payment',
  ]);
```

Comment: @Subhhais thank u sir , also another question : how can i make the user's email in my website the same as stripe's email and not editable

Comment: I did but I need at least 15 reputation, so basically it  have been recorded !

Comment: What do you mean by user email and stripe email?