# Adding extra information to Stripe payment intent

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I have implemented Stripe in my Flutter app, but I would like to add some information to the payment done in order to recognize the payment inside the payments list inside the Stripe dashboard panel.

This is the response from Stripe when generating a payment:

```
// 1. Create a payment intent on the server
      final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(
              'https://...stripePaymentIntentRequest'),
          body: {
            'email': email,
            'amount': amount.toString(),
            'description': widget.codigo_pedido ,
          });

      final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print("respuests stripe: ${jsonResponse.toString()}");


respuests stripe: {paymentIntent: pi_3M6dBTCcyi0G23rG0FoA7fEl_secret_h6dewQiWveMe5HsPg5MxCduTB, ephemeralKey: ek_test_YWNjdF8xR3NQRm5DY3lpMEcyM3JHLHFiV3ZQRkpBM3VHNHNFOFM3RHJvemxiYlpyaTRSazA_00HIJiGkLl, customer: cus_MqJLygEutMbF4X, success: true}
```

Is there a way to add some extra information inside the payment intent?

Comment: Yes you would want to utilise the metadata fields, these are also searchable later on for reference https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-metadata. You can use this to store a user_id for example from your DB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i insert metadata details or expand new properties using stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496016/how-can-i-insert-metadata-details-or-expand-new-properties-using-stripe)

Comment: @OMiShah, that would be great, but I don´t know where exactly in my current code should I add the extra info

Comment: @OMiShah, the given example is for PHP, which is using another way to send the needed information to Stripe

Comment: @mvasco, what endpoint is this ``https://...stripePaymentIntentRequest`` ? Your server/backend endpoint?

Comment: @OMiShah, yes, it is a JavaScript Firebase function

Comment: then you should be adding the additional info to the ``metadata(key-value pair)`` key with your existing request data in your function. Check official integration in Node.js https://youtu.be/KxBwIhncYD8?t=148

Comment: @OMiShah, nice, let me try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store additional information on the Payment Intent object, you can add a [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object?lang=php#payment_intent_object-metadata). Metadata is a key-value pairs that can be attached to an object. To learn more, you can review this [document](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#storing-information-in-metadata).

Your server side code should look something like this:

```
$stripe->paymentIntents->create(
  [
    'amount' => 1099,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'metadata' => ['order_id' => '6735'],
  ]
);
```